# Replacing occurrences of strings in NSString while maintaining case of original string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have some local HTML and CSS that I display using a UIWebview. I want to incorporate search hit highlighting.

Here is my highlighting method:

```c
-(void) highlightsSearchTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm
{
    NSString *highlightedSearchTerm = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span class='highlight'>%@</span>",searchTerm];

    NSString *highlightedArticle = [article.articleHTML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:searchTerm withString:highlightedSearchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [article.articleHTML length])];

    article.articleHTML = highlightedArticle;
}
```

The issue with this is that it replaces, for example, `Obama` with the user's search query, which might have been `obama` (note the case). I want to maintain the case of the original article while incorporating the hit highlighting.

I'm hoping for a more elegant solution than manually finding the starting and ending indexes of each hit term and then inserting `<span class="highlights">` and '' respectively.

Basically I want something like:

```c
+ [NSString stringByWrappingExistingString:(NSString *)stringToWrap withString:(NSString *)wrappingString options:NSCaseInsensitiveCompare];
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSRegularExpression` to do this (code typed in directly, check for errors):

```
NSRegularExpression *re = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"Obama" 
                                                                    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                      error:NULL];
NSString *output = [re stringByReplacingMatchesInString:inputString
                                                options:0
                                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, inputString.length)
                                           withTemplate:@"<span class='highlight'>$0</span>"];
```

The regular expression search string, `@"Obama"`, is straightforward in this case as you are looking for a literal match; the option `options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive` makes the match case-insensitive.

While the example uses a literal *Obama* you can obviously construct the string dynamically; **however** be careful in that case about using strings which contain regular expression meta-characters, they will need to be escaped.

The replace template contains `$0` which will be replaced by what was matched (*exactly*, so preserving case).

Comment: Out of curiosity, which approach would you consider "better" and why: yours or mine? I like mine because it stays away from regular expressions (maybe not a good reason to stay away), but I like yours because it's terse.

Comment: @TRedman - "Better" is somewhat subjective. The above is both shorter and more flexible - should you need to, say, change all occurrences of "green jelly" to "jelly (green)" preserving the case of the original the code would be just as short. There is also room for the framework to optimize more, e.g. the multiple replacements compared to doing them one at a time. In general Use a higher-level approach if you can; and only go lower-level if *and only if* you hit a performance issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```c
-(void) highlightsSearchTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm
{
    NSString *openSpan = @"<span class='highlight'>";
    NSString *closeSpan = @"</span>";

    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, article.articleHTML.length);
    NSRange foundRange;

    NSString *highlightedArticle = article.articleHTML;

    while (searchRange.location < highlightedArticle.length)
    {
        searchRange.length = highlightedArticle.length - searchRange.location;

        foundRange = [highlightedArticle rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:searchRange];

        if (foundRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            // found an occurrence of the substring! do stuff here
            searchRange.location = foundRange.location + foundRange.length;

            NSString *casePreservedSearchQuery = [highlightedArticle substringWithRange:foundRange];
            NSString *styledSearchQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", openSpan, casePreservedSearchQuery, closeSpan];

            highlightedArticle = [highlightedArticle stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:foundRange withString:styledSearchQuery];

            //increase the current location by the length of new string - search query length
            searchRange.location = searchRange.location + [styledSearchQuery length] - [casePreservedSearchQuery length];
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    // no more substring to find
    article.articleHTML = highlightedArticle;
}
```

Comment: you've really saved me, awesome answer!